# Изменение интерфейсных элементов по таймеру

Tags: uwp, таймер

Здравствуйте.
Разрабатываю универсальное приложение, столкнулся с простой на первый взгляд проблемой, но так и не смог ее решить.

Упрощаю задачу чтобы была понятна суть - есть окно на нем кнопка, в конструкторе формы создаю таймер:

```
  m_Timer = new System.Threading.Timer(DoTickTimer, this,1000,1000);

private void DoTickTimer(object _state)
{
  btn.Text = "oops";//обновляю интерфейсный элемент
}
```

Понятно что `btn.Text = "oops"` нужно заставить выполняться в главном потоке, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо, как часто и бывает, после того как задал вопрос, ответ ищется легче :)
Проблему решил следующим образом

```
 AutoResetEvent signal = new AutoResetEvent(false);
 m_Timer = new System.Threading.Timer(DoTickTimer, this,1000,1000);
 private void DoTickTimer(object _state)
 {
    signal.Set();//устанвка эвента в потоке таймра
 }
 public async void DoRun()//инициализация механизма 
 {
   while (true)// Да, это бесконечный цикл, но он не блокирует основной поток, хотя и запущен в нем, по хорошему добавлю сюда условия выхода.
   {
     await Task.Run(()=>ListenTimer());//запуск в отдельном потоке 
     Tick();//это уже выполняется в главном потоке.
    }
  }
  void ListenTimer()
  {
    signal.WaitOne(2000);//жду установки эвента от таймера (тоже в отдельном потоке)
  }
```

PS:
Как я потом понял таймер в этой конструкции лишний, вполне работает схема когда я ожидаю никогда не устанавливаемое событие signal.WaitOne(2000); определенное время. Для этого вместо 2000 нужно устанавливать желаемый интервал срабатывания. При этом, естественно не нужна и функция DoTickTimer

Comment: таймер действительно лишний

Answer (score 0):

```
public static async Task CallOnUiThreadAsync(DispatchedHandler handler) =>
            await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, handler);


void DoSomething(); // то, что нужно выполнить в потоке GUI

await Task.Run(async() => 
{
    while(true) 
    {    
         await Task.Delay(ms); 
         await CallOnUiThreadAsync(() => DoSomething()); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UWP, запуск функции в UI потоке можно выполнить так:

```
Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, ()=>
            {
                btn.Text = "oops";//обновляю интерфейсный элемент
            });
```